# Connection to ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache2

I am a new user in this environment, so I had a lot of questions for which I found answers on the internet. However, this one took a lot of time and I still didn't figure it out. I hope you can help me, please.

As a challenge to check how fast can I learn new things I was told to:
1.install SQL server 2016 (express) on my Windows 10.
2.on VirtualBox install Ubuntu 16.04
3.restore a database from a .bak file on my computer.
4.connect to that server from ubuntu on virtual box. (I followed these steps https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/blob/master/README.md) PHP version is 7.1

After I was done with this on my final step I got this error:

> SQLSTATE: 08001 Code: 11002 Message: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.

So I started fixing this error.
1. I configured remote access following these steps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option) Using SQL Server Management Studio
2.I configured windows firewall to open access to SQL Server when using dynamic ports.
3. I checked if server's name was correct. (and it was, as well as the password, username and etc.)

Assuming all of this was done right, I still can't connect to ms sql.
What should I do or what did I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: why did you delete the error info ?

Comment: hi, sorry, I put it back

Answer (score 0):

As you had posted error regarding

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.

You may try this :

1. Open Sql Server Configuration Manager --> Protocols for 
   --> TCP/IP --> IP Addresses(Tab).
2. Go to the last entry IP All and mention TCP Port 1433.
3. Now restart SQL Server () using services.msc

Please try this, if this didn't work, we may proceed with other troubleshooting stuff.

**update1**
Next step is to try the following :

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Right click SQL Server instance -> Properties -> Connections -> 
   Check the Allow remote connections to this server box.
3. Go to the General section and check name of SQL Server specified in
   the Name field.
   [image: screenshot :]

Comment: I tried, didn't help. By the way, the Status bar for TCP/IP was Disabled, just in case I tried to enable it and retry connection, but it didn't help either

Comment: Hey, so I googled around and apparently I had to enable SQL Server Browser. This solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so I googled around and apparently I had to enable SQL Server Browser. This solved the problem, thanks!